# How DC and AC relays works?

Tags: electromagnetism

I was told long time ago that DC relay had a coil. There was a switch (2 wires, one is stable, the other one is flexible) inside the coil. The switch was parallel to the axial direction of the coil.

Today, I am thinking how AC relay works. I go back to think about DC relay. If what I was told is right, the magnetic field direction is parallel to the switch direction. Then how the magnetic field makes two wires touch?

Also, how does AC relay work?

Comment: What kind or relay?. There are many types. For example, Solid State Relays can be either DC/AC

Comment: coil base mechanical type relay

Comment: Would http://electronics.stackexchange.com/ be a better home for this question?

Answer (score 1):

This question is not about solid state relays.

In a DC solenoid type relay, a permanent magnet (sliding center core) moves and actuates switch contact(s) when energized.  These are typically used in automotive applications, to provide current to a starter motor through fusible links.

Although AC solenoid type relays might be possible, it would be much trickier to mechanically engineer one that operated like their DC counterpart because the center iron core (not magnetized) would need to pull against a retaining spring.  That would mean it would normally reside outside of the coil.  It is far easier to make AC relays which when energized simply attract a chunk of iron riveted to the end of a lever which actuates the switch contacts.